# how to substract two dates (type: datetime) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have this column named: **temps** in dataframe  named :**df**

```
0      2022-03-18 14:50:11
1      2022-03-18 14:50:00
2      2022-03-18 14:49:59
3      2022-03-18 14:48:00
4      2022-03-18 14:40:00
```

information about my dataframe df

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 172 entries, 0 to 171
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------       --------------  -----         
 0   temps        172 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   id           172 non-null    int64
```

i need to subtract each two succéssive row and get the results with seconds

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.view(int)` to convert the dates to numbers, `.div(1e9)` to convert the resulting nanoseconds into seconds, and `.diff()` to compute the difference between each successive row:

```
df['temps'] = df['temps'].view(int).div(1e9).diff().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   temps
0    0.0
1  -11.0
2   -1.0
3 -119.0
4 -480.0
```